# Grouping AutoShape in Word Document using Interop.Word

Tags: c#, office-interop

I've tried to draw AutoShape in Word using Interop.Word 12.0 in C# language. I've some AutoShape object in the document. How to group that AutoShapes using that Interop.Word 12.0?

There is a way grouping AutoShape object using VBA but there is one method that doesn't exist now (document.Shapes.get_Range(...)).

Answer (score -1):

```
 ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 80.25, 478.5, 39#, _
        61.5).Select
    ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 131.25, 487.5, 71.25, 48.75) _
        .Select
    ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("Oval 9", "Rectangle 8")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Group.Select
```

Read above macro